# Apply Multiple Checkbox Values to a Label C#

Tags: c#

I have a groupbox with ten different checkboxes with different pizza toppings.  When I check multiple boxes I want the name of the toppings to show up as a string on a label I have below the groupbox.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read the [faq]'s and [ask]. I cant see the groupbox you are referring to. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. All you have to do is have a `string` member variable and concatenate it with the CheckBoxList's selected items, then assign the string to the `label.Text`.

Comment: You've nailed writing the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead of using simple check boxes, use a CheckedListBox control
(otherwise you must handle each check box click event separately)

So when you are done addnig 10 items in a CheckedListBox, then set its property:
`CheckonClick` to true

Then double click the control and use the following code:

```
Label1.Text+=checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " ";
```